# Laravel view foreach with two properties

Tags: php, html, laravel

i need help with my foreach loop in view

**Controller.php**

```
$expenses = Expense::groupBy('category_id')->selectRaw('sum(amount) as sum, category_id')->pluck('sum','category_id');

$categories = Category::all();

return view('dashboard.index', compact('expenses','categories'));
```

**index.php**

```
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th>Expenses</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @foreach($categories as $category)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
                @foreach($expenses as $expense)   
              <td>{{ $expense }}</td>
              @endforeach
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

I get the output like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PrP6.png)

It outputs the expense 2 times, is there a limiter for "foreach loop" or is there another way on doing this?

Comment: try to add relation between expenses and categories. Then you can call expenses with categories so it will be easy to run only one loop. From laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I'm new to laravel, I will also try this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a condition for that `$category->id` is the same as `category_id`

```
 @foreach($expenses as $key => $expense)   
    @if($key == $category->id)
    <td>{{ $expense }}</td>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

The right way to do it is by using join or relationship.

```
$expenses = Expense::join('categories','categories.category_id','expenses.category_id')->groupBy('expenses.category_id')->selectRaw('sum(expenses.amount) as sum, expenses.category_id','categories.name')->get();

<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Expenses</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

         @foreach($expenses as $expense)   
          <th>{{ $expense->name }}</th>
          <td>{{ $expense->sum }}</td>
         @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this later when i get home.

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the results in controller, but here's how you can accomplish this in a blade. Not pretty

```
@foreach ($element['subs'] as $item)
    @if($loop->index < 10)
        // Your code
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: By saying not pretty, do you mean this is a bad practice? Thank you.

Comment: @JamesMacxy Its best practice to use Controller like a controller and use Views as a views, then we can call it MVC structure.

Comment: @JamesMacxy don't forget to validate my answer in case your problem is solved by it

Comment: how can i validate it?, your answer is working but as you said not pretty, i did not pursue it and tried to use other way and used dilip code also works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare `category_id` with `category->id`.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
    @foreach($expenses as $expense)
        @if($expense->category_id == $category->id )   
            <td>{{ $expense->sum }}</td>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this later when i get home.